# Configure HC-05

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, android, hc-05

I am trying to send/receive data from Android to my Arduino (via a HC-05) and later from Arduino to Android. I have configured my HC-05 as slave, and the UART=9600,0,0.... To send data from Android to Arduino I don´t have problem but to send data Arduino to Android I can not...

This is my sketch:

```c
char data;
int a=1;
int v=1;
#include SoftwareSerial connection(10,11);//RX|TX
void setup() 
{
 pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
 connection.begin(9600);
 digitalWrite(7,LOW);
}

void loop() 
{
 if(connection.available()>0)
 {
  data=connection.read();
   if(data=='1')
   {
    digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
    connection.write(data);
    delay(200);
   }
   //connection.write(data);
  }
 }
```

MY HANDLER IN THE MAIN:

```
       mhandler=new Handler()        {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)            {
            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case MENSSAGESEND:
                    msg = new DriveData((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);    //DriveData msg = new DriveData((BluetoothSocket)msg.obj);
                    break;
                case MESSAGEREADING:
                    byte[] bufferget = (byte[])msg.obj;
                    String men = new String(bufferget,0,msg.arg1);
                    sb.append(men);
                    int endline=sb.indexOf("\n");
                    if(endline>0)
                    {
                        String print=sb.substring(0,endline);
                        sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"menssage"+" "+print,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        txtData.setText(print);
                    }
                    break;

            }
        };
    };
```

MY METHOD FOR RECEIVER AND SEND DATA

```
  public void run()
    {
        byte[] wait=new byte[1024];
        int bytesReceived;
        while (true) {
            try {
                 bytesReceived=entrydata.read(wait);//entrydata is my inputstream
                mhandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGEREADING,bytesReceived,-1,wait).sendToTarget();
            }catch (IOException e){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but.. what is the line `#include SoftwareSerial conexion(10,11);//RX|TX`?

Comment: what is HC-05 ?

Comment: @alcor Bluetooth module. I'd add more details to the question but the Android app is annoying to use.

Comment: HC-05 is model from bluetooth for my connection                                                #include SoftwareSerial is the library for use pin´s as RX and TX on arduino UNO, "conexion" is the name from my connection is as variable

Comment: Are you sure it's not a simple hardware problem - like the TX pin being disconnected?  You are handling the HC-05 at 3.3 volts right?

Comment: No, i have Volt to 5v from arduino, my bluetooth can be using with 3.3v or 5v

Comment: @FidelPinedaSantos Just a friendly tip. Code in English, that way it's times easier to read for others.

Comment: @avamander I have already changed my codec to english, sorry

Comment: @FidelPinedaSantos Have you tried using some of the examples available on the web for communication with this combination of hardware?

Comment: I can receive data from android, but i can not yet send data from arduino to android

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the line termination
you must send '\n' after your data in order to receive the data
or use 
conexion.println(entrada) 
rather then
conexion.write(entrada)

Comment: I already did these, but not work, only i can send data from android to arduino